# c# windows forms display output code on windows cmd

Tags: c#, cmd

It possible display output (exit code) on windows cmd from windows forms app. Example

```
 [STAThread]

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Count() > 0)
        {
            Environment.Exit(4);
            return;
        }

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

And I run app using windows cmd:

```
 start test.exe param1 param2 param3
```

And I want get output on a windows console "4". I tried return int instead void,
close app using Environment.Exit(4), Console.Writeline

Comment: `echo %ErrorLevel%` in `cmd` window?

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question correct than you need a `Console Output`.

Create a `Windows Form` project...

Then: **Project Properties -> Application -> Output Type -> Console Application**

Then you can have `Console` and `Forms` running together.